# C# winform ms report. "The rport definition for report 'WPP-108' has not been specified'

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I am doing this in Visual studio 2012.

```
    dsCaseActivity = CaseActivitiesWarehouseInfo("75,76");         
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "CustomerService-SS.WPP-108.rdlc";
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsWareHousepickpack", dsCaseActivity.Tables[0]));
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

The datasource is dsWareHousepickpack, spelled correctly and I am passing in 2 records from the dataset table.

How can I get rid of this error.  I have looked and tried to set the report path but that did not work.
Thanks

Comment: Does the `Report` from difference project than where the `ReportViewer` is ?

Comment: No the report is in the same project as the report viewer.

Comment: Try remove then add the local report to report viewer again by design view. If it does not work try with report path when make sure you set the report `Copy to output...` property to `Copy if newer` or `Always`. Also try with a different report to check if the error persist. This error come from many source, if you can't find out, try simplify your code (remove sensity data) and send me the link if you need help.